# Lista completa Skype Uri

Tags: c#, html, skype

Buenos días, en estos momentos me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto para manejar ciertas funciones de Skype por medio de unos URI que ellos mismos ofrecen, como por ejemplo para realizar una llamada, el cual tiene la siguiente forma.

```
<a href="skype:usuarioallamar?call">Llamar</a>
```

Ahora bien, tengo entendido que hay un URI para hacer vídeo llamadas, iniciar el Skype, hacer conferencias... A lo cual quisiera saber en que lugar puedo encontrar una lista completa de los comandos que podría utilizar y su sintaxis.

Postada, la pregunta debería llevar etiquetas de Skype y también de URI, pero no las puedo poner porque no existen todavía en Stack Overflow en español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Llamadas de voz**

Sintaxis:

```
skype:participant1[;participant2;...participant9]
```

Llamar directo a un usuario:

```
skype:skype.test.user.1
```

Llamar a una conferencia de usuarios:

```
skype:skype.test.user.1;skype.test.user.2;skype.test.user.3
```

**Advertencia**:

> Mobile Skype clients (iOS and Android) do not support
>   initiating/hosting conference calls.

**Video llamada**

Sintaxis:

```
skype:participant1[;participant2;...participant9]?call&video=true
```

Video a un usuario:

```
skype:skype.test.user.1?call&video=true
```

Video a varios usuarios (modo conferencia):

```
skype:skype.test.user.1;skype.test.user.2;skype.test.user.3?call&video=true
```

La lista completa la puedes encontrar en:

Referencia: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx

Comment: En español: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/dn745882.aspx

Comment: bien jugado @sstan! :D