# Ejecutar Skype URI desde aplicación de escritorio C#

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, aplicación-escritorio

Buenos días, estoy trabajando en C#, aplicaciones de escritorio, con tecnología WPF. En el sistema debe haber un botón el cual levante una llamada de skype, para lo cual utilizo uno de los [URIs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29760/lista-completa-skype-uri) que ofrece skype:

```js
<a href="skype:usuarioallamar?call">Llamar</a>
```

Ahora bien, en estos momentos lo que tengo un archivo html, el cual llamada a la instrucción anterior a penas se abre el html. Mi idea era la que poner un control `WebBrowser` invisible y que ejecutara el script, al ver que no me funcionaba lo hice visible, así pude ver que el problema me bloquea el Script que se ejecuta en el `window.onload` y este bloqueo lo hace cada vez que ejecuto el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, también intenté ponerle nombre a la función de JavaScript y llamarla por medio del método `WebBrowser.InvokeScript()`, pero tampoco me ha funcionado, pues me dice que no encuentra la función con dicho nombre.

A lo que viene mi pregunta, existe alguna manera de llamar a un script en WPF para aplicaciones de escritorio, o sí existe una propiedad del WebBrowser que tenga que cambiar para que no bloquee el script.

Posdata:

1. El WebBrowser es el de la librería `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`
2. El Script sí funciona, ya lo probé abriendo desde windows el archivo html
3. El nombre del Script también está correcto, pues también lo probé desde el link que se ve en la imagen.

   ```html
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="llamadaSkype;">
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenos días, ya pude encontrar la solución al problema. Al final utilicé el control de `Systems.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, que tiene la propiedad `.Url`, a la cual se asigno `new Uri ("skype:usuarioallamar?call")` y realiza la llamada por Skype.